# How to Upload Screenshots to Microsoft Store for Windows 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I published one Windows 10 app to the store with the respective screen shots.

I have now developed the same app for Windows 8.1 universal and the screenshots are different from the Windows 10 app.

How can I upload Windows 8.1 universal app screenshots?

Answer (score 7):

You can take screenshots of your app using the emulator within Visual Studio.

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442300(v=vs.105).aspx) goes into detail on how to take a screenshot. I appreciate it's aimed at Windows Phone 8 however it works in just the same way for Windows Phone 8.1.

To create an app screenshot using the built-in emulator screenshot tool:

> 1. To optimize the quality of your screenshots, set the zoom level of the emulator to 100 percent. The higher you set the zoom level, the better the quality of the screenshot. For more information, see How to adjust the zoom setting in the emulator for Windows Phone 8.
> 2. Start your app in the emulator.
> 3. On the emulator toolbar, click the expand button to open the Additional Tools window.
> 4. Click the Screenshot tab.
> 5. When your app is ready, click the Capture button. The screenshot appears in the workspace.
> 6. Click the Save button to open the Save As dialog box.
> 7. Choose the location and File name that you want, and then click Save.
> 8. Optionally, navigate to other pages in your app and capture additional screenshots.
> 9. Launch an emulator with a different screen resolution to capture the same screenshots at a different resolution. If you ran your app with debugging, you have to stop debugging before you can run it again on another emulator.

I've done a few images to try and give a bit of guidance.

On the emulator toolbar, click the expand button to open the **Additional Tools** window:

[image: Emulator toolbar]

**Additional Tools** window:

[image: Additional Tools window]

On this window is where you would select **Capture** to capture a screenshot of whatever page your app is currently on.

To then upload these screenshots, on your submission to the App Store you want to look at the **Store Listings** section:

[image: Store Listings]

In here is where you can upload your screenshots:

[image: Upload screenshots]

**To create platform-specific Store listings**

As described in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/create-platform-specific-store-listings) you can create platform-specific store listings:

> Near the top of your **Store listing** page, you'll see a link to **create a platform-specific app Store listing** if you have uploaded packages that support earlier OS versions ((Windows 8.x or earlier and/or Windows Phone 8.x or earlier).
>
> When you click the link to **create a platform-specific app Store listing**, a popup will appear asking you to choose from your supported targeted operating systems. Windows 10 is not included in the list of choices, because customers on Windows 10 will always see the app's default Store listing.
>
> You can use your default Store listing as a starting point, which will bring over all of the text and images you've entered for your default Store listing; you'll then be able to make any changes you'd like before saving. You can also start from a completely blank Store listing if you prefer.
>
> After you click **Continue**, your **Store listing** page will now include a section for the platform-specific Store listing you've just created (underneath the Default Store listing section). This section will include its own set of fields for **Description** (required), **Release notes, Screenshots, App tile icon, App features**, and **Additional system requirements**. Make sure to enter info into each field where you want to display info in the custom Store listing, even if it's the same info as in your default Store listing. If you leave any of these fields blank, no info will appear for that field in the custom Store listing.